# Doctrine 2 + Zend Framework 2 Persistent when saving foreign key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

My problem is when I try persist a Entity with array (without object) the column with foreign key becomes null (if is a new registry) but if is a Update (without persist), no problem appears

The Function

> abstract class AbstractCrudController extends AbstractAckActionController {
>
> private function save($dataToSave = array()) {
>
> ```
>         $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
>         $entity = $this->getEntity();
>
>         if (true) {
>
>             if (null != $dataToSave['id']) {
>                 $entity = $entityManager->getRepository($this->getEntity(true))
>                         ->findOneBy(array('id' => $dataToSave['id']));
>             }
>             $entity->save($dataToSave); // commit changes to db
>
>             if (null == $dataToSave['id']) {
>                 $entityManager->persist($entity);
>             }
>
>             $this->debug($dataToSave);
>
>             $entityManager->flush();
>
>             if (false !== $entity->getId()) {
>                 $this->flashSuccess('sucess');
>                 $this->ackRedirect('listar');
>             } else {
>                 $this->flashError('fail');
>             }
>         } else {
>             $this->flashError('Form invalid');
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> }

The entity abstract parent

```
namespace Base\Entity;

abstract class AckEntity {

    /**
     * Return all valyues of entity in one array
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllArray(){
        $array = get_class_methods($this);
        $size = count($array);
        $elements = array();
        $exist = false;
        for($i = 0; $i<$size; $i++){
            if('getAllArray' != $array[$i])
            if(substr($array[$i], 0, 3) == 'get'){
                $a = substr($array[$i], 3);
                $a = lcfirst($a);
                $elements[$a] = $this->$array[$i]();
                $exist = true;
            }
        }
        if($exist)
        return $elements;
        return null;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        $name = 'get' . $name;
        if (is_callable(array($this, $name))) {
            return $this->$name();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public function save($param) {
        $param = $this->preSave($param);

        foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
            $functionSet = 'set' . $key;
            $functionAdd = 'add' . $key;

            if (is_callable(array($this, $functionSet))) {
                $this->$functionSet($value);
            } else if (is_callable(array($this, $functionAdd))) {
                $this->$functionAdd($value);
            }
        }
        $param = $this->posSave($param);
        return $param;
    }

    public function preSave($param) {
        if (is_array($param)) {

        } else if (is_object($param)) {

        }
        return $param;
    }

    public function posSave($param) {
        return $param; //$this->flush();
    }

}
```

The entity

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AcsUsergroup
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acs_usergroup", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_57698A6AB8C2FD88", columns={"title"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_57698A6A727ACA70", columns={"acs_usergroup_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AcsUsergroup extends \AckBase\Entity\AckEntity {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="acs_usergroup_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $acsUsergroupId;

    /**
     * @var AcsUsergroup
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AcsUserGroup", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="acs_usergroup_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $acsUsergroup;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="block", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $block = '0';


    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getParentTitle() {
        $group = $this->getAcsUsergroup();
        if (null != $group)
            return $group->getTitle();
    }

    function getAcsUsergroup() {
        return $this->acsUsergroup;
    }

    function getAcsUsergroupId() {
        return $this->acsUsergroupId;
    }

    function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function getBlock() {
        return $this->block;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setAcsUsergroupId($acsUsergroupId) {
        if ('' == trim($acsUsergroupId)) {
            $acsUsergroupId = null;
        }

        $this->acsUsergroupId = $acsUsergroupId;
    }

    function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    function setBlock($block) {
        $this->block = $block;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using doctrine/zend 1 or 2? Why both tags? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Doctrie 2 and zend 2, i'll fix the tags, thanks.
My problem is when I try persist a Entity with array (without object) the column with foreign key becomes null (if is a new registry) but if is a Update (without persist), no problem appears

Comment: What input data are you using?

Comment: array (with only string and integer).
for the foreign key i'm using integer.